# Is it possible to partially update rows using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Suppose I have a table like this:

[image]

and an array of objects which contains `[
  {ID: '0', Name: 'Leo', Age: 21, CurrentState: 5},
  {ID: '1', Name: 'George', Age: 26, , CurrentState: 6},
  {ID: '2', Name: 'Diana', Age: 27, , CurrentState: 4}
]`.

How can I update the columns `ID`, `Name`, `Age`, and `CurrentState` without affecting the values of `IsAdmin` column?

If I run the following code

```
Table.bulkCreate([
  {ID: '0', Name: 'Leo', Age: 21, CurrentState: 5},
  {ID: '1', Name: 'George', Age: 26, , CurrentState: 6},
  {ID: '2', Name: 'Diana', Age: 27, , CurrentState: 4}
], {
  updateOnDuplicate: true
})
```

All the values of `IsAdmin` of the updated rows will be set to `FALSE`, which is its default value.

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just passe an array of only the attributes that need to be updated

```
Table.bulkCreate([
  {ID: '0', Name: 'Leo', Age: 21, CurrentState: 5},
  {ID: '1', Name: 'George', Age: 26, , CurrentState: 6},
  {ID: '2', Name: 'Diana', Age: 27, , CurrentState: 4}
], {
  updateOnDuplicate: ['Name','CurrentState']
})
```

[options.updateOnDuplicate](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

- Array
- optional
- Fields to update if row key already exists (on duplicate key update)? (only supported by mysql). By default, all fields are updated.

Comment: Thank you. I made a stupid mistake for not reading the document clearly.